# How to prove the monotonicity of the following function with respect to $\alpha$?

Tags: calculus

1)$\frac{\Phi}{\Omega}$ 
2)$\frac{\Delta}{\Omega}$

where

$\mu_(\alpha)=\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)(\epsilon-1)+1}{(1-\alpha-\beta)(\epsilon-1)}$

$
\Omega (\alpha)=(1-\beta)^\frac{(1-\beta)(1-\epsilon)+\epsilon}{\epsilon}-\left(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{\mu}\right)^\frac{(1-\beta)(1-\epsilon)+\epsilon}{\epsilon}\mu^\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}
$

$
\Delta (\alpha) =(1-\beta)^\frac{(1-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}-\left(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{\mu}\right)^\frac{(1-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}\mu^\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}
$

$
\Phi (\alpha) = \left(\theta\beta+\frac{\theta}{\epsilon-1}\right)\Delta +\left(\frac{1}{\mu}-1\right)(1-\alpha-\beta)\left(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{\mu}\right)^\frac{(1-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}\mu^\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}
$

Independent variable: $0<\alpha< 1-\beta$,

Constant: $\beta<1$,   $\epsilon>1$, $0<\theta<1$

We have plotted it using Mathematica and it seems that both of them are increasing with respect to $\alpha$. However, we are hoping to get an analytical proof. Thanks in advance.

Results we have proven and varified using Mathematica:

$\Delta>0, \Omega>0$,
$\left(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{\mu}\right)^\frac{(1-\beta)(1-\epsilon)+\epsilon}{\epsilon}$ and $\mu^\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$ is increasing with respect to $\alpha$

Comment: Well what did you try? What happens if you derive wrt to $\alpha$? Anyhow I feel that this question is too specific for this site

Comment: Your function is not at all clear. Please state which of your symbols are constants, which are your independent and dependent variables, and which are intermediate variables.

Comment: @Ant Thanks for reminding me, we've tried proving a couple of things, and update the question with some results that we've proven. We've calculated the total derivative with respect to $\alpha$, but it's not clear whether the derivative is positive or negative.

Answer (score 1):

Here are my two cents.

let $a = (1-\beta)^{\frac{(1-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}}$ and   $b =\left(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{\mu_m}\right)^\frac{(1-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}\mu_m^\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$

$$ Part \quad 1$$

then we have $\Omega=a(1-\beta)-b\left(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{\mu_m}\right)$ and  $\Delta=a-b$. Now the function $\frac{\Omega}{\Delta}$ can be written as

$\frac{a(1-\beta)-b\left(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{\mu_m}\right)}{a-b}=\frac{(a-b)(1-\beta)+b(1-\beta)-b\left(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{\mu_m}\right)}{a-b}=1-\beta+\frac{b}{a-b} \dot \large[(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\frac{1}{\mu_m})]$

$=1-\beta+(\frac{a}{a-b}-1) \dot \large[(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\frac{1}{\mu_m})]$

In order to show the function $\frac{\Omega}{\Delta}$ is decreasing, we can show that $b$ is decreasing and $[(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\frac{1}{\mu_m})]$ is decreasing.

$$1$$
$(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\frac{1}{\mu_m})=(1-\alpha-\beta)-\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{1+\frac{1}{(\epsilon-1)(1-\alpha-\beta)}}=(1-\alpha-\beta)-\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)^2 (\epsilon-1)}{1+(\epsilon-1)(1-\alpha-\beta)}$

$(1-\alpha-\beta)-\left[(1-\alpha-\beta)-\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{1+(\epsilon-1)(1-\alpha-\beta)}\right]=\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{1+(\epsilon-1)(1-\alpha-\beta)}=\frac{1}{\epsilon-1+\frac{1}{1-\alpha-\beta}}\leftarrow decresing$

$$2$$

b is also decreasing

$b =\left(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{\mu_m}\right)^\frac{(1-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}\mu_m^\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$

From 1 we can easily show that $\left(\alpha+\frac{1-\alpha-\beta}{\mu_m}\right)^\frac{(1-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$ is decreasing.

So we want to show that $\mu_m^\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$ is decreasing as well.

Therefore, we will use $\mu_m=1+\frac{1}{(\epsilon-1)(1-\alpha-\beta)}=1-\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon(1-\epsilon)(1-\alpha-\beta)}$

We define $g(x)=\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}$, then we have:

$$h =\mu_m^\frac{(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\epsilon)}{\epsilon}=\left(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon}\frac{1}{g}\right)^g$$

We let $y=ln(h)$ $(h<1, so y<0)$,

$\frac{dy}{y}=ln(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon g})+g\cdot(\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon g-1}-\frac{\epsilon}{\epsilon g})$

$=ln(1-\frac{1}{\epsilon g})+\frac{1}{\epsilon g-1}>0$

$dy/dg<0 \rightarrow dy/d\alpha<0$

Therefore b is also decreasing.

$\frac{\Omega}{\Delta}$ is decreasing, hence $\frac{\Delta}{\Omega}$ is increasing.

$$ Part \quad 2 $$

Similarly, we can obtain $\frac{\Phi}{\Delta}$

$\frac{\Phi}{\Delta}=\left(\theta\beta+\frac{\theta}{\epsilon-1}\right)+ \frac{b}{a-b}\cdot \large[(1-\alpha-\beta)(\frac{1}{\mu_m}-1)]$

Together with $\frac{\Omega}{\Delta}$, we have

$\frac{\Phi}{\Omega}=\frac{\left(\theta\beta+\frac{\theta}{\epsilon-1}\right)+ \frac{b}{a-b}\cdot \large[(1-\alpha-\beta)(\frac{1}{\mu_m}-1)]}{1-\beta+\frac{b}{a-b} \dot \large[(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\frac{1}{\mu_m})]}=\frac{\left(\theta\beta+\frac{\theta}{\epsilon-1}\right)- \frac{b}{a-b}\cdot \large[(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\frac{1}{\mu_m})]}{1-\beta+\frac{b}{a-b} \dot \large[(1-\alpha-\beta)(1-\frac{1}{\mu_m})]}$

Obviously, it is decreasing.